# JSON error checking if statement

Tags: php, json

I am new to json and would like to display json error message and error code if errors exist.
I am using php as well.

So far I have assigned two variables:

```
$error_num = json_last_error();
$error_msg = json_last_error_msg();
```

But I am confused what I should put into the if statement.
I believe it should be of some terms like : if error exists ... 
But I have not enough experience to understand how I could do this.

```
if (/* ERROR condition is true */) 
{
    echo "Error: " . $error_num . " " . $error_msg;
}
else
{
  // .. DISPLAYS TABLE ..
}
```

I would appreciate any help you could give me as I am only learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

> Its Returns the last error (if any) occurred during the last JSON
>   encoding/decoding.

```
<?php
// A valid json string
$json[] = '{"Organization": "PHP Documentation Team"}';

// An invalid json string which will cause an syntax 
// error, in this case we used ' instead of " for quotation
$json[] = "{'Organization': 'PHP Documentation Team'}";


foreach ($json as $string) {
    echo 'Decoding: ' . $string;
    json_decode($string);

    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**refer link http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php**

Answer (score 0):

To check if json_decode has no error try this :

```
 if ($error_num !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) 
 {
   echo "Error: " . $error_num . " " . $error_msg;

 } else { 
  // .. DISPLAYS TABLE ..
 }
```

`JSON_ERROR_NONE` is a PHP constant and it means **No error has occurred**